# Ninject Kernel Scope

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

I'm new to Ninject, and I was wondering if the scope of the kernel should be 1 per application. So should I treat the kernel as a singleton?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should. More precisely - You should have one root container. It's OK to create context specific subcontainers.

Comment: Should the Kernel be passed around, or how do you access the kernel? Should classes be aware that they need to get an instance of an object they want to use by calling kernel.get<>(), or should all dependencies be injected into the constructor?